# point cloud color in pcd format

Tags: modeling, python, point-clouds

I am trying to visualize point clouds with color in blender but I cannot achieve that. I understand that the ply or stl format does not support the point cloud color but now I am trying with the *.pcd format but when I loaded the point cloud, it has again no color. Does someone any idea about how to do it?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hello ! ply supports color data. You may want to try the PCV addon https://github.com/uhlik/bpy/blob/master/space_view3d_point_cloud_visualizer.py or https://www.blendermarket.com/products/pcv